# What type of tree to use for this kind of scheme?

Tags: database, database-design, tree

I'm trying to build a contact manager. I have a datastructure in mind that has a couple of properties:

- it is tree like, meaning that each piece of information can be split up into subpieces (each node has children). For example a field called `address` may consist out of `street`, `town`, `postal code`, etc subfields.
- nodes do not have to be unique, for instance several nodes of the `email` field should be able to coexist next to each other (at the same level)

I would like to be able to explore the tree using a path-like manner, e.g. access nodes by path: `address.street` or `name.first`. Accessing nodes whose key is present more than once could be done like `email[2]`.

so a tree could look like:

```
contact
   ↳ name
        ↳ first      "foo"
        ↳ last       "von bar"
   ↳ email           "foo@bar.com"
   ↳ email           "baz@foo.de"
   ↳ address
           ↳ street  "foostreet 42"
           ↳ town    "barstadt"
           ↳ zip     "04229"
           ↳ country "footopia"
   ↳ address
           ↳ street  "barton alley 11"
           ↳ town    "foostadt"
           ↳ zip     "998877"
           ↳ country "alcabaz"
```

what kind of tree is this? I've tried using the Boost's `property_tree` but found it hard to implement the fact that `address` should be split at high level (Boost's standard method would  put the `street`, `town`, ... nodes in one `address`).

Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what kind of tree is this?

It's a tree ;)

You can use JSON and the Jackson Lib for modelise your tree :

http://www.mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/

Comment: any C++ libs that you can recommend?

Comment: http://jsoncpp.sourceforge.net/ or if you using Boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html